# Is there any weighted sobolev embedding with non-decaying weight

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations

Is there any weighted sobolev embedding like 
$$(\int_{R^d}(1+|x|)^s |u|^pdx)^{1/p}\leq C||\nabla^a u||_{L^q}$$?
Here $s>0$, and for some appropriate $p, q$.

Comment: Take any $u\in C_0^{\infty}$ and consider $u(x+L)$: the LHS grows $\sim L^{s/p}$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I guess if $u$ is radially symmetricinequality might be true. If we don't assume radial symmetric, will the inequality still hold, but with the constant $C$ depend on $u$?